¿Cómo puedo hacer consulta a varias tablas en .NET8?
Buen día a todos.
Como dice el título, estoy intentando consultar los datos de varias tablas que están relacionadas a través de una tabla pivote, tengo las tablas jugadores, equipos y campeonatos y estas se relacionan a través de una tabla llamada rosters, la cuestión es que estoy intentando obtener los datos de cada una de las tablas pero no logro hacer correctamente los join entre ellas a través de la tabla rosters.
Este es el código del método que estoy utilizando.
[HttpGet("GetPlayersByRoster/{championshipId}/{teamId}")]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Roster>> GetPlayersByRoster(long championshipId, long teamId)
    {
        var roster = await _context.Rosters.Include(r => r.Player)
                                .Include(r => r.Championship)
                                .Include(r => r.Team)
                                .Where(r => r.ChampionshipId == championshipId && r.TeamId == teamId)
                                .ToListAsync();

        return roster;
    }

Estas son las clases involucradas.
public class Championship
    {
        [Key]
        public long Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(200)]
        public required string Identifier { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

        public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public required bool InProgress { get; set; }

        public long? FederationId { get; set; }

        public long? AssociationId { get; set; }

        public long? LeagueId { get; set; }

        public required long CategoryId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("FederationId")]
        public Federation? Federation { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("AssociationId")]
        public Association? Association { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("LeagueId")]
        public League? League { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("CategoryId")]
        public Category? Category { get; set; }

        public List<Roster>? Rosters { get; set; }

        public List<ChampionshipSponsor>? ChampionshipSponsors { get; set; }

        public List<ChampionshipCondition>? ChampionshipConditions { get; set; }

        public List<ChampionshipTeam>? ChampionshipTeams { get; set; }

        public DateTime? CreatedAt { get; set; }

        public DateTime? UpdatedAt { get; set; }
    }

public class Roster
    {
        [Key]
        public long Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public DateTime SaveDate { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(15)]
        public required string UniformNumber { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public long ChampionshipId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public long TeamId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public long PlayerId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ChampionshipId")]
        public Championship? Championship { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("TeamId")]
        public Team? Team { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("PlayerId")]
        public Player? Player { get; set; }

        public List<OffensiveStat>? OffensiveStats { get; set; }

        public List<PitchingStat>? PitchingStats { get; set; }

        public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }

        public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }
    }

public class Player
    {
        [Key]
        public long Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(200)]
        public required string Dni { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(200)]
        public required string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(200)]
        public required string SecondName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(200)]
        public required string Surname { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(200)]
        public required string SecondSurname { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(10)]
        public required string Gender { get; set; }

        public List<Roster>? Rosters { get; set; }

        public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }

        public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }
    }

public class Team
    {
        [Key]
        public long Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(200)]
        public required string Name { get; set; }

        public List<Roster>? Rosters { get; set; }

        public List<AssociationTeam>? AssociationsTeams { get; set; }

        public List<TeamCategory>? TeamCategories { get; set; }

        public List<FederationTeam>? FederationTeams { get; set; }

        public List<LeagueTeam>? LeagueTeams { get; set; }

        public List<ChampionshipTeam>? ChampionshipTeams { get; set; }

        public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }

        public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }
    }

Este es el erro que me arroja cuando intento hacer la consulta


Debes agregar un ejemplo mínimo de las clases involucradas, señalar que es lo que no funciona de esa consulta y cual sería el resultado esperado

@Yussef listo ya edite todo para mostrar mas a detalle el problema que se me presenta.

La consulta está bien, el problema se origina al momento de pasar esos objetos a JSON. Tú tienes una referencia circular, tu clase Roaster contiene un Player que a su vez contiene a una lista de Roaster que tiene a Player y así infinitamente. Lo cual te genera un JSON con una profundidad infinita, cuando el máximo en tu caso es 32.
Soluciones hay muchas y dependerá de tu lógica de tu sistema
1) Eliminar referencia circular
Tienes 2 clases A y B, tú puedes navegar de A->B o B->A. Lo cual es util, pero en muchos casos no es necesario. Entonces puedes eliminar una propiedad de navegación y así solo te quedas con A->B. Por ejemplo, en tu caso podrias eliminar todos los public List<Roster>? Rosters { get; set; } de las clases Championship, Player y Team. Siempre podrás navegar desde Roaster hasta alguna de ellas, pero no en sentido contrario
2) [JsonIgnore]
Ahora bien, digamos que para la lógica de tu sistema es necesario navegar en ambos sentidos. No obstante, lo que no es necesario es enviar esos datos al cliente. En este caso puede utilizar [JsonIgnore] y no enviar esa propiedad de navegación, por ejemplo:
[JsonIgnore]
public List<Roster>? Rosters { get; set; }

3) Configurar el comportamiento de referencia cíclica
Puedes configurar a modo global como se comportará la serialización para las referencias cíclicas. Esto se configura en el Program.cs
3.1) Ignorar
Ignora toda referencia cíclica
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(x => x.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles);

3.2) Preservar
Preserva toda referencia cíclica, pero agregando metadadata, utilizando prefijos $, donde va referencia objetos. Lo cual permite al cliente rehacer toda la referencia circular.
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(x => x.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.Preserve);

4) DTO
Esto es crear una clase Ad-hok para transferir los datos que tu estimes necesarios.
Otra opción parecida pero menos prolija es simplemente devolver una clase anónima
public async Task<IEnumerable<object>> GetPlayersByRoster(long championshipId, long teamId)
=> _context.Rosters
        .Include(r => r.Player)
        .Include(r => r.Championship)
        .Include(r => r.Team)
        .Where(r => r.ChampionshipId == championshipId && r.TeamId == teamId)
        .Select(r=> new //RostersDTO
        {
            r.Id,
            Player = new { r.Player.Id},
            //etc

        });


Perfecto, me funcionó agregando el [JsonIgnore] a mis modelos. Luego intentare hacerlo usando DTOs ya que voy a necesitar hacer algunos json mas personalizados, muchas gracias.
